# i need to make a program that lies 5 to 20 percent of the time

Tags: python, python-2.7

i am making a simple program that that asks you to guess a number and tells you wheter or not you were

a: too high

b: too low

or c: spot on

and i want this program to lie to you 5 to 20 percent of the time it lets you know how close you are. 
this is my current code:

```
start = 'yes'

qwe = raw_input('want to play a game?:')
if qwe == start:
    import random
    value = random.randrange(1, 100)
    original = -1
    score = 0
    while original != value:
        score = score + 1
        original = int(raw_input('pick a number between 1 and 100:'))
        if original == value:
            print "you win your score is", score
        elif original >value:
            print 'too high'
        else:
            print 'too low'
else:
    print "that's unfortunate"
```

Comment: Draw a random number from 0 to 100. If the number is less than the integer percentage, have it lie, else tell the truth. You could obviously also generate a number between 0 and 1, and check if the number is less than the decimal percentage instead.

Comment: Also you will have to decide what *"5 to 20 percent of the time"* means, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

just replace your `print` statements by

```
print(lie_about("too high","too low"))
```

and

```
print(lie_about("too low","too high"))
```

where `lie_about` is defined as:

```
import random

def lie_about(true_answer,false_answer,true_chance=0.8):
    return true_answer if random.random()<true_chance else false_answer
```

(defaults at lying 20% of the time, you can adjust it in the third optional parameter)

BTW: If you have to choose which percentage, 5 to 20, you can choose that at random too, although it appears far-fetched...

```
def lie_about(true_answer,false_answer):
    true_chance = random.uniform(0.8, 0.95)
    return true_answer if random.random()<true_chance else false_answer
```

Comment: You could use `true_chance = random.uniform(0.8, 0.95)`